# Making Canvas fill parent in SolidJs

Tags: css, frontend, styling, solid-js

I'm working in [SolidJs](https://www.solidjs.com) and using [HopeUi](https://hope-ui.com) for some components.

I use the [grid component](https://hope-ui.com/docs/layout/grid) from HopeUi, and I want to fill one of the grids with a canvas component.

The code for my App currently looks like this:

```js
import './App.css'
import { Grid, GridItem } from "@hope-ui/solid"

function App() {

  return (
    <>
      <Grid 
        h="90vh" 
        templateRows="repeat(2, 1fr)" 
        templateColumns="repeat(5, 1fr)" 
        gap="$4"
      >
        <GridItem rowSpan={1} colSpan={1} bg="black" />
        <GridItem colSpan={2} bg="papayawhip" />
        <GridItem colSpan={2} bg="papayawhip" />
        <GridItem id='c' colSpan={5} bg="tomato">
          <canvas id='c' width='100vw' height='100vh' style="border:1px solid #000000;"/>
        </GridItem>
      </Grid>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

The resulting page looks like this:
[image]

I've tried setting the height and width to both 100% and 100vw/vh, but to no luck.

How can I make the canvas fill the parent grid without hardcoding the size?

Answer (score 0):

The `width` and `height` attributes of a canvas represent the number of pixels for drawing and should be integers. To visually fill the canvas within its positioned parent, you can use a function like this:

```
function fitToContainer(canvas) {
  canvas.style.width = '100%';
  canvas.style.height = '100%';
  canvas.width = Math.floor(canvas.offsetWidth);
  canvas.height = Math.floor(canvas.offsetHeight);
}

// Example usage
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
fitToContainer(canvas);
```

Comment: Where should this go in the context of SolidJs?

Comment: @VetleHofsøy-Woie Here is how you do it in SolidJS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77709877/7134134

Answer (score 0):

According to [specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas#width), `width` and `height` properties of `canvas` will take values in `px` only (not vm or %).

You can change its `width` and `height` with css or inline styling:

##### CSS

```css
canvas {
   inline-size: 100vw; /*width*/
   block-size: 100vh;  /*height*/
}
```

##### HTML

```html
<canvas style="width:100vm"></canvas>
```

Note that this doesn't help with canvas `width` and `height` which they are real sizes that canvas **API** uses to determine your canvas dimensions and accordingly all shapes that it draws inside this canvas.
You must use **javascript** for solving this:

```js
// you must have set it's sizes in css or style
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth;
canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight;
```

If you're interested why canvas `width` and `height` properties not behave the same as css `width` and `height`, that's because they are not for styling and actually not same as css `width` and `height` properties except for their names.

They are just properties of canvas object like `name` is a property of `foo` object in:

```js
const foo = {name: 'mahdi'}
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is stated in the other answers, you need to need to use pixel value with the canvas element.

If you need to interact with the underlying element imperatively, it is best to use a ref:

```js
function App() {
  let canvas;

  onMount(() => {
    // Intreact with the element
    canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth;
    canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight;
  });

  return <canvas ref={canvas} />;
}
```

You can find a working demo: https://www.solidjs.com/tutorial/bindings_forward_refs